# .net slide-in menu

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

What's the best way to have a floating side/top menu that expands when you mouseover to reveal several menu items/links?

I assume something like jquery is the best option but where to begin?
Is there a jquery plugin that does all of the above?

Comment: All of the above could be done in CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by looking into some jQuery Dropdown Plugins aleady available in the Net. They're free and reduces your workload by a ton. No cross-browser compatibility issues also :)

Eg:- http://slodive.com/web-development/best-jquery-dropdown-menus/

Comment: How about one that you just click and then it becomes a top menu, then goes back to one menu item when you mouseout?